# looping numpy error: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I want to write the following code:

```
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        Ab(i,j) = (Ap(i)*Ap(j))^(0.5)*(1 - kij(i,j)) ;
    end
end
```

However an error appears: "all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)"

```
ab=np.matrix((2, 2))
for i  in range(0,nc):
  for j in range(0, nc):
    np.append(ab,((Ap[i]*Ap[j])**(0.5)*(1 - kij[i][j])))
```

Comment: what `np` stand for?

Comment: That's the error described in the last example in the [documentation of np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). Did you check the dimensions? Can you fix the dimensions as in the example?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit context missing, but if I guess correctly looking at Matlab part you can write something like this.

```
ab = np.zeros((2, 2)) 
for i in range(ab.shape[0]): # you do not have to put 0 and you can use size of array to limit iterations
  for j in range(ab.shape[1]):
    ab[i, j] = (Ap[i]*Ap[j])**(0.5)*(1 - kij[i][j])))
```

**My assumptions**

- ab matrix meant to be 2x2 matrix, not 1x2 matrix with values [2, 2], this what np.matrix confusingly does (at least these were my expectations coming from Matlab). np.zeros - creates array with all zeros of size 2x2. Array and matrix are a bit different in numpy, by matrix is being slowly deprecated (more here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html?highlight=matrix#numpy.matrix)
- nc - is size of ab matrix

**Why you had an error?**

- np.matrix((2, 2)) - creates 1x2 matrix with values 2 and 2 [[2, 2]]
- (Ap[i]*Ap[j])**(0.5)*(1 - kij[i][j])) - this looks like a scalar value
- np.append(ab, scalar_value) - tries to append scalar to matrix, but there is dimensions mismatch between ab and scalar value, which is stated in the error. Essentially, in order for this to work, they should be similar types of objects.

*Examples*

```
>>> np.zeros((2, 2))
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
   
>>> np.matrix((2, 2))
matrix([[2, 2]])

>>> np.array((2, 2))
array([2, 2])

>> np.append(np.matrix((2, 2)), [[3, 3]], axis=0)
matrix([[2, 2],
        [3, 3]])

>> np.append(np.zeros((2, 2)), [[3, 3]], axis=0)
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [3., 3.]])
```